# How to add a href link in PHP?

Tags: php, html, href

I'm very new to PHP and trying to make a site update on the fly.

I need to update the code so that the link will direct to www.otherwebsite.com. Currently the link directs to the current websites RSS feed.

Here is the original div:

```
<div style="float:right;">
<a href="<?php echo url::site(); ?>feed/"><img src="<?php echo url::file_loc('img'); ?>media/img/icon-feed.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" border="0"></a>
```

I need to alter this to point to www.someotherwebsite.com. It looked simple enough. Here is what I tried:

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <a href="<?php echo www.someotherwebsite.com"><img src="<?php echo url::file_loc('img'); ?>media/img/twitter.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" border="0"></a>
```

That never worked, instead I received an error message concerning the line where I had made this edit.

How would I update this?

Comment: If you're hardcoding it, why not just put it into the HTML directly?

Comment: Also, you forgot a double quote after `echo`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you missed a few closing tags and you nshould have "http://" on the front of an external URL. Also, you should move your styles to external style sheets instead of using inline styles.

```
.box{
  float:right;
}
.box a img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0px;
}

<div class="box">
    <a href="<?php echo "http://www.someotherwebsite.com"; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo url::file_loc('img'); ?>media/img/twitter.png" alt="Image Decription">
    </a>
</div>
```

As noted in other comments, it may be easier to use straight HTML, depending on your exact setup.

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="http://www.someotherwebsite.com">
        <img src="file_location/media/img/twitter.png" alt="Image Decription">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the input, will update just now

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to invoke PHP for this. Just put it directly into the HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">...
```

Answer (score 4):

you have problems with " :

```
 <a href=<?php echo "'www.someotherwebsite.com'><img src='". url::file_loc('img'). "media/img/twitter.png' style='vertical-align: middle' border='0'></a>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in HTML

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```